# Can't build PSmove API with MinGW 5.3.0, multiple definitions

Tags: c++, mingw, linker-errors

I downloaded the PSmove API source code from https://github.com/thp/psmoveapi. Then I generated the makefile using CMake 3.14.0-rc2. As the next step I used Code::Blocks 17.12 to start the build process with minGW 5.3.0 under Windows 10 64-bit.

The compiling process works fine, but then during the linking process I receive the following error messages:

Linker error:

[image: linker error]
<sup>(Click images to enlarge)</sup>

Log before error appears:

[image: log before error appears]

There are a lot of multiple definitions in libpthread and libmingwex and at the moment I am a bit lost how to get rid of this errors.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! See why we [discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/1362568)